# Are there health benefits from using a massage chair on a regular basis?

Tags: healthcare, massage

http://www.humantouch.com/massage-chair-benefits.html make a series of claims regarding the health benefits from regularly using a massage chair:

> Regular massage offers **several measurable health benefits** that
>   help promote everyday health. By **increasing circulation**, your body
>   can pump more oxygen and nutrients to tissues and vital organs, which
>   promotes faster healing and a return to a health state. Regular
>   massage also **stimulates the lymph system** – the body's natural
>   defense against toxic invaders – to help avoid sickness and promote an
>   overall sense of wellbeing. And massage prompts the body to **release
>   endorphins**, the body's natural painkiller, easing sore, tired
>   muscles.
>
> Beyond physical benefits, massage helps **reduce stress, anxiety and
>   fatigue**, and allow the body and mind to be better in tune. This is
>   significant when considering both short- and long-term stress triggers
>   changes in the body increasing the likelihood of getting sick, raising
>   the risk of serious conditions like heart disease, and can make
>   problems we already have worse.
>
> In summary, the cumulative effects of regular massage can **strengthen
>   and tone the entire body to help prevent unnecessary strains and
>   injuries that might otherwise occur due to excess tension**. Never has
>   something so comfortable, indulgent and convenient helped so many
>   people feel better, play better and perform better.

I see that many of those claims are echoed on other popular health websites. Are they all true?

I am aware of [Are there health benefits from traditional massage therapy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2961/7654), but this question focuses on  massage *chairs*.